# How to add "jni/*.c/cpp" files to CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, android-ndk, include

I have created a new project including c++ ndk. So it automatically created a `CMakeLists.txt` file and a `cpp` directory. But When I created a new directory named `jni` and tried to put `test.c`, `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` files on it, I got this error message when I wanted to sync my project:

> This file is not part of the proejct.please include it to appropriaten
>   build file

Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ndktest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
```

Application.mk :

```
APP_ABI := all
```

test.c :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_m_ndktest_MainActivity_testJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());

}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_m_ndktest_MainActivity_testJNI2(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hellooooo");

}
```

How should I include my `.mk` files inside the `CMakeLists.txt` ?

CMakeLists.txt :

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

[image]

> ***Also I have a question, where can I find the tutorial about the STRANGE syntax that we should write in Android-ndk? (I mean the test.c
>   syntax that I copied from the default `native-lib.c`)

Comment: _"where can I find the tutorial about the STRANGE syntax that we should write in Android-ndk?"_ Which syntax are you referring to? The function naming convention? That's described [in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html).

Comment: _"How should I include my .mk files inside the CMakeLists.txt ?"_ You don't. You pick _one_ of CMake or ndk-build and use that; not both of them.

Comment: @Michael: you say if I want to build a library with ndk-build like `tesseract` I shouldn'g fill the check box `including support for c++` at the project wizard?

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio has the concept of external native builds. And for these external native builds, you have [two](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) options:

- ndk-build
- CMake

CMake seems to be the more modern one, so is probably more future-proof. I advice using that one.

This means that you write a `CMakeLists.txt` file (which is typically in your `jni/` directory.)

You no longer need any of the .mk files, they are used by the ndk-build external native build, not the CMake one.

To indicate which of the external native build systems you use, you use the app's gradle file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "..."
                arguments "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the CMakeLists.txt file, you describe how to build the native .so library. This includes listing all the `.c` and `.cpp` source files that are required to build it. This is done with CMake's [add_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) macro.

So to summarize, your new project definition will consist of gradle files, and one (or more) CMakeLists.txt file, but no longer will you need any .mk files.

Answer (score 1):

> if I want to build a library with ndk-build like tesseract I shouldn'g fill the check box *including support for c++* at the project wizard?

The check box is not a problem, you simply edit your **build.gradle** script and replace `cmake` that the wizard inserted with `ndkBuild`.